# Why does my C++ program keeps freezing when user gives a float from the command line?

Tags: c++, command-line-interface

I'm writing a program in c++ that will find the sum of a power set.  I wanted to include some error handling to weed out things like 0, characters, or non-whole numbers.  My strategy was simple.  The program enters an infinite while loop and can only get out if the modulus of the user input is zero.
What I expected to happen: User enter 2.4 (2.4 % 1 = .4, .4 != 0) the program loops again and tells the user to enter a whole number.
What happens: User enters 2.4, the program freezes.

Can someone tell my what's going on?

Thanks

```
// This C++ program will compute sum of all subsets of a set "S" stored 
// in an array data structure.  We assume that these subsets are the 
// powerset of S and not the permutation set.  
// The program workflow is as follows:
//
// 1)   Prompt the user to provide the length and elemets to a custom array, if none, use 
//      the default array.
// 2)   The user creates a custom array.
// 3)   Sort the array using the QuickSort function.
// 4)   Get the sum by running the SubArraySum function

#include<iostream>
#include<limits>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std; 

// Utility functions for quicksort
void Swap(int *x, int *y)
{
    int temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

int RemoveDuplicates(int arr[], int size)
// This function removes duplicate elements by setting their value to 
// zero.  This works because the purpose of the main code is to sum the subarrays.
// Adding zero to the sum multiple times does not change the sum.  However, technically this will
// shorten the array.  
// So, we need to keep track of the number of duplicates and give this to the SubArraySum
// function since it used the length of the array to calculate the sum.   
{
    int dupCount = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < size-1; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] == 0)
        {
            ;
        }
        if(arr[i] == arr[i+1])
        {
            arr[i] = 0;
            dupCount++;
        }
    }

    return dupCount;
}

int Partition(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    int i = low - 1;
    int pivot = arr[high];

    for(int j = low; j <= high - 1; j++)
    {
        if(arr[j] < pivot)
        {
            i++;
            Swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
        }
    }
    Swap(&arr[i+1], &arr[high]);

    return i+1;
}

void PrintArray(int arr[], int size)
{
    cout << "[ ";
    for(int i = 0; i < size-1; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << ", ";
    }
    cout << arr[size-1] << " ]" << endl;
}

// Quicksort to sort the array
void QuickSort(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    if(low < high)
    {
        int p_idx = Partition(arr, low, high); // p_idx is the partition index
        QuickSort(arr, low, p_idx-1);
        QuickSort(arr, p_idx+1, high);
        
    }
}


void GetSum(int arr[], int n, int dupCount) 
// Computes sum all sub-array 
// arr[] is an array provided by the user or if none given the 
// default array is arr[] = {1,2,3,4...10}
{ 
    int p = pow(2, n-1-dupCount);
    long int sum = 0; 

    //cout << "These are the subarrays: " << endl;
    // The outer forloop picks the starting point for each subarray
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++) 
    { 
        sum += p*arr[i];        
    } 
    cout << "This is the sum: " << sum << endl; 
} 

void SubArraySum(int arr[], int size)
{
    PrintArray(arr, size);  
    QuickSort(arr, 0, size-1);
    int dupCount = RemoveDuplicates(arr, size);     
    GetSum(arr, size, dupCount);
}

void DefaultSubArraySum()
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); 
    SubArraySum(arr, n);
}


// Driver program to test above function 
int main() 
{   
    cout << "Enter a whole number for the length of the array or enter 0: ";    
    
    // This while loop will chatch any entries that were not whole numbers and force 
    // the user into a loop until they give a valide number.
    
    double user_length;
    cin >> user_length;
    while(1)
    {
        double is_whole = fmod(user_length,1.0);


        if(cin.fail())
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
            cout << "Entry invalid.  Please enter a whole number or enter 0: ";
            cin >> user_length;
        }

        if(is_whole != 0.0)
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
            cout << "Entry invalid.  Please enter a whole number or enter 0: ";
            cin >> user_length;
        }

        

        if(is_whole == 0.0)
        {
            break;
        }

    }
        
    // If the user does not specify an array the default sub array sum will be calculated.  
    if(user_length == 0.0)
    {
        // Default code if the user enters 0.
        DefaultSubArraySum();

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "this user_length: " << user_length << endl;
        int arr[(int)user_length];
        cout << "Enter your array values: "  << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < user_length; i++)
        {
            cout << i+1 << ": ";
            cin >> arr[i];
            
        }       

        int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); 
        SubArraySum(arr, n);
        
    }
        
    
    int clear_buffer = cin.get();
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: Very likely it's getting stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Careful with `int arr[user_length];`. That's a Variable Length Array, and for a wide variety or reasons they aren't legal in Standard C++. If the user gives a large enough number, it'll exhaust the Automatic Storage, probably a stack, and Kaboom. Program goes insane.

Comment: That's too much unrelated code for the problem that you are seeing. Please create a [mcve] and post it.

Comment: No need for `int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);`. if `n` isn't `user_length` something's gone horribly, horribly wrong.

Comment: @user4581301, Yes, I agree.  I might put in some logic to take care of this later, but right now I'm just creating example codes as part of a job prep.

Comment: `int is_whole = user_length % 1;` is always 0, because `user_length` is always a whole number. `int user_length; cin >> user_length;` can't store a float in an int-variable. Maybe that's not the root of your problem, but you should consider it.

Comment: So is_whole is always zero and both your if statements that check it check for is_whole != 0 so it doesn't EVER detect that is_whole is 0.  One of those if statements should be is_whole == 0

Comment: Also according to the logic you describe above _"The program enters an infinite while loop and can only get out **if the modulus** of the user input **is zero**."_ it seems like `if(is_whole !=0) { break; }` is a typo.

Comment: I'm not sure what a job prep is, but you're you're making code samples to submit choose carefully. I'd leave out `using namespace std;`, that is looked down upon (with good reason) in professional circles. `Swap` should be implemented with references. Shows you know more than just C.

Comment: Come to think of it, I'm usually more interested in an applicant who knows not to reinvent the wheel and uses `std::swap`, `std::sort` and the other tools of the trade..

Comment: @user4581301, Thanks for the tips!  I going over different coding challenges that are given to interviewees and I came across this one "create a program that can sum all of the sub-sets of a given set a.k.a. the power set"  C++ is not my main language, I prefer Python, but I felt that C++ was a good language to get strong with, so I created the script above.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah, Thank you, you were correct.  But, after I removed the second if statement and changed the the if(is_whole != 0) { break; } to if(is_whole == 0) { break; } the program started freezing again.

Comment: @churill, Thank you for your first comment!  The problem was that I was using % which is a binary operator and couldn't handle a double.  I change the code by adding #include<cmath> and fmod(x,y).  Now the program runs without freezing.  I'm still getting odd behavior, like entering a char will default to 0.0 and the program runs the default function, but at least I'm past this problem.  Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it helped. You shouldn't compare floating point values for equality however, floating point calculations are prone to rounding errors, so you might get unexpected behaviour where two should be equal, but actually differ in the last decimal place or so. Maybe the best would be to read a whole line and try to parse it as int, so you always get a whole number or parsing failure.

Comment: Glad to help. When you're practicing C++, make sure to look in the Standard Library (especially [the algorithm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) and [utility](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility) libraries) to see if there's a canned solution already available. Also understand RAII and [the Rules of Three, Five, and Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). The Rule of Three is an early wash-out question for me. If a C++ programing candidate gives a blank stare when I ask what it is, odds are high the candidate was taught C and told it was C++.

Comment: @user4581301, Thanks for the heads up and the links.  This is actually the first time I've heard about rule 3/5/0.  Likewise, I've had some experience with multi-threading and mutex, but I hadn't seen the RAII acronym before.  Glad to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the problem was that I was using % for my modulus operator.  This is a binary operator and it was failing when I ran it with the variable int user_length.  To fix this problem I removed `#include<math.h>` and added `#include <cmath>`.  I removed the % operator and replaced it with the fmod(x,y) function.  This corrected the freezing problem.  However, the code is still struggling with chars.  For some odd reason, if a char is entered twice consecutively, is_whole becomes 0 and my default function gets run.  A big shout out to @churill for spotting the % mod conflict.

Here is a simplified, mostly working code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<limits>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std; 

void PrintArray(int arr[], int size)
{
    cout << "[ ";
    for(int i = 0; i < size-1; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << ", ";
    }
    cout << arr[size-1] << " ]" << endl;
}


// Driver program to test above function 
int main() 
{   
    cout << "Enter a whole number for the length of the array or enter 0: ";    
    
    // This while loop will chatch any entries that were not whole numbers and force 
    // the user into a loop until they give a valide number.
    
    double user_length;
    cin >> user_length;
    while(1)
    {
        double is_whole = fmod(user_length, 1.0);
        cout << "This is the value of is_whole: " << is_whole << endl;


        if(cin.fail())
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
            cout << "Entry invalid.  Please enter a whole number or enter 0: ";
            cin >> user_length;
        }
        
        if(is_whole != 0.0)
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
            cout << "Entry invalid.  Please enter a whole number or enter 0: ";
            user_length = 0;
            cin >> user_length;
        }       

        if(is_whole == 0.0)
        {
            break;
        }

    }
        
    // If the user does not specify an array the default sub array sum will be calculated.  
    if(user_length == 0.0)
    {
        // Default code if the user enters 0.
        cout << "The user entered 0 " << endl;

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "this user_length: " << user_length << endl;
        int arr[(int)user_length];
        cout << "Enter your array values: "  << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < user_length; i++)
        {
            cout << i+1 << ": ";
            cin >> arr[i];
            
        }       

        int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); 
        PrintArray(arr, n);
        
    }
        
    
    int clear_buffer = cin.get();
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Next step for you: debug your program. There are many ways depending on your IDE. However, I suggest GDB

Comment: @Leos313, Yes, I agree.  I recently switch to VS code and I'm still learning how to run their debugger.

Comment: it is always crucial